# differential equation second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this differential equation (second order)

> $$y''+5xy'-3y=0 , \quad y(0)=1, \quad y'(0)=1$$

I have to find a power series solution .The problem is that I dont have any idea how to do it Can you please give me an example for this kind of differential equation and it's solution? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This differential equation involves the ***Hermit Polynomial***  and the ***Kummer confluent hypergemetric*** functions, are you familiar with these or is there a typo ?

Comment: I don't know either of these functions.

Comment: Check again the differential equation given for a typo (mistake) then, since there is no point even trying to work around these if you're not familiar with them. Maybe there's a mistake in the way you copied the problem ?

Comment: Perhaps you're meant to find a power series solution?  That is reasonably elementary.

Comment: Are you familiar with the term Cauchy-euler equation? Perhaps you meant to have an $x^2$ in front? What is the general context you are studying this in?

Comment: Yes, that's what is meant to find @RobertIsrael

Comment: Ah. In that case I guarantee you your book has some examples that should familiarize you with how to solve it. You basically start out assuming you have a series solution and plug it into the equation.

Comment: write $y=\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ then $y'=\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty} na_nx^{n-1}$ and so on for $y''$. Report in the ODE and reindex the sums so you can identify coefficients before $x^n$ to $0$. This will give an equation for the $a_n$. Isolated terms (for $x^0,x^1,x^2$ possibly) have to be dealt with saparately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y''+5xy'-3y=0 , \quad y(0)=1, \quad y'(0)=1 \tag 1$$
The general solution of the ODE is :
$$y(x)= c_1e^{-5x^2/2}\:_1F_1\left(\frac45\:,\:\frac12\:;\:\frac52x^2 \right) +c_2e^{-5x^2/2}\:U\left(\frac45\:,\:\frac12\:;\:\frac52x^2 \right) $$
$_1F_1$ denotes the confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind (Kummer's function).

$U$ denote  the confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind (Tricomi's function). It reduces to an Hermite polynomial in case of integer parameter, which isn't the present case.

CONDITIONS : $\quad y(0)=y'(0)=1$.

Note : This is the correction of a calculus mistake in my first answer.

$U\left(\frac45\:,\:\frac12\:;\:0 \right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(13/10)}\quad$ and $\quad\frac{d}{dx}\left(U\left(\frac45\:,\:\frac12\:;\:x \right)\right)_{x=0}=\frac{4\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{5}}}{\Gamma(9/5)}$

$1F_1\left(\frac45\:,\:\frac12\:;\:0 \right)=1\quad$ and $\quad\frac{d}{dx}\left(_1F_1\left(\frac45\:,\:\frac12\:;\:x \right)\right)_{x=0}=\frac85 $

Solving $\quad\begin{cases}
y(0)= c_1+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(13/10)}c_2=1\\
y'(0)=\frac85c_1+\frac{4\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{5}}}{\Gamma(9/5)}c_2=1
\end{cases}\quad$ gives $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $$\eqalign{y(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \cr
 y'(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) a_{n+1} x^n\cr
 y''(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)(n+1) a_{n+2} x^n\cr}$$
You'll find that the coefficient of $x^n$ in $y'' + 5 x y' - 3 y$ involves
$a_n$ and $a_{n+2}$.  Setting this to $0$ gives you a recurrence equation.
With $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 1$ from the initial conditions, you can easily
compute the first several coefficients.  If you're more ambitious, you can find closed form formulas for $a_n$ using the Gamma function.