# Reducing a second order ODE to a hypergeometric equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I want to solve the following second order ODE with non-constant coefficients: $$y^{\prime\prime} + (ax+b) y^{\prime} + (cx+d)y = 0,\tag{1}$$
where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. From what I understand, its solution involves confluent hypergeometric functions of the first and second kind; e.g., see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2597957/differential-equation-second-order). In particular, it appears that finding the solution of (1) involves finding the solution of the degenerate hypergeometric equation
$$xy^{\prime\prime} +\left(\frac{1}{2} -x\right)y^{\prime} -ey=0,\tag{2}$$
where $e\in\mathbb{R}$ is some appropriately determined constant (not to be confused with Euler's number). Alas, I could not quite figure out the procedure for finding the general solution from that post.

Not only would I like to understand the solution of (1), but I would like to know how to "reduce" the problem from solving (1) to solving (2). (The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function) on the confluent hypergeometric function lays out the steps for this reduction when we have a non-constant affine coefficient on the $y^{\prime\prime}$ term in (1), but not when the coefficient is a constant.) I have skimmed over the book by Abramowitz and Stegun but didn't find it particularly helpful, although I'm sure that my question is embedded in their development. Other references would be delightful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you posted is much more complex than the one in the linked post.
$$y^{\prime\prime} + (ax+b)\,y^{\prime} + (cx+d)\,y = 0$$ The idea is first to find a transform such that the multiplying factor of $y$ does not depend on $x$.

So, let $y=z\,e^{f(x)}$. Cheating a little, I found that
$$f(x)= -\frac{a }{2}x^2+ \left(\frac{c}{a}-b\right)x$$ does the job.

Replacing, we end with
$$z''-(ax+\alpha)z'+\beta z=0\tag 1$$ where
$$\alpha=b-\frac{2 c}{a} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \beta=\frac{-a^3+a^2 d-a b c+c^2}{a^2}$$ As you can see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermiteDifferentialEquation.html) changing variable, we have Hermite differential equation.

So the general solution of $(1)$ is a linear combination of a confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind and an Hermite polynomial.

Comment: Thank you very much! Regarding the change of variable to get the Hermite differential equation, are you referring to eliminating the $\alpha$ term in (1)? If so, does an adjustment need to be made to $f$ to accomplish this? Also, I now see that the solution involves a Hermite polynomial $H_{n}$ for some integer $n$. According to the link you shared, $n=\lambda/2$ where $\lambda$ is the coefficient on the $y$ term. However, in general $\lambda$ need not be even. In that case, is the solution just given by equation (9) in that link? @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Would you be able to explain how to eliminate the $\alpha$ from your equation (1) to obtain the Hermite differential equation? I have tried various substitutions but none seem to give me what I want. @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: @Satana. You need to change variable too to arrive to the normal form of Hermie DE.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know what the change of variable is to bring it to the normal form? I tried an exponential transformation in a similar way that you did. I was able to eliminate the $\alpha$ but I ended up with an extra constant term in (1). So ultimately it didn't work  @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: @Satana: Have a look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve%5By%27%27%5Bx%5D+%2B+%28a+x+%2B+b%29+y%27%5Bx%5D+%2B+%28c+x+%2B+d%29+y%5Bx%5D%3D%3D0%2Cy%5Bx%5D%2Cx%5D